# Python NameError and I can not understand

Tags: python, return, return-value, definition

I'm now practicing defining functions:

```
def get_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    return 3600*hours+60*minutes+seconds
```

Now, I want to exec the function:

```
amount_a = get_seconds(7200*minutes+30*seconds)
amount_b = get_seconds(__)
result = amount_a + amount_b
print(result)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'minutes' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you define "get_seconds" function, you just need to do :

```
amount_a = get_seconds(hours=2, minutes=30, seconds=0)
amount_b = get_seconds(hours=0, minutes=45, seconds=15)
```

Comment: Oh that worked! I didn't realized I had to set the syntax that adds meaning to hours, minutes and seconds. Appreciate it!

Comment: It's great! More practice more exp~